# What exactly does "drafting" in "drafting body" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I've been wondering about the term "drafting body" for bodies that prepare different matters in an organisation; I understand the use of "drafting" when there's actually a draft for something being drawn up, but as I understand it, this term ("drafting body") is used also for bodies that just **prepare** cases, without actually drafting any documents as such.

So, I'm wondering whether "draft" also has a wider meaning of 'prepare' besides the more concrete meaning of writing a first version of a document? I've checked some dictionaries, but haven't been able to find an answer to this...

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever encountered the term "drafting body" before anyway, but its meaning would have to be at least *somewhat* "context-specific". Possibly in a large organisation it turns out to be useful to have a more "general-purpose" department look into new projects before they get so far as needing to produce any "draft" documents (because the people who will eventually be assigned to produce the relevant drafts might be too bound up in the specific project to assess things properly from a company-wide perspective, perhaps). There's no special sense of "draft" involved here.

Comment: drafting means writing. No doubt about it. to draft a document is to write it.

Comment: MW: : to draw the preliminary sketch, version, or plan of
draft legislation
b: COMPOSE, PREPARE
draft a memo//In other words, to write.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, these are the definitions I've found as well; I was just wondering since bodies of the kind that I thought "drafting body" referred to don't always draft anything in this sense. But I've probably misunderstood the meaning of "drafting body"...

Comment: There are all types of bodies: scientific, legislative, administrative, etc. etc. etc. I just wonder where you saw this...

Comment: @Lambie I found it in my university's bilingual word list... that is, my university lists the English translation of the corresponding term in my own language as "drafting body".

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, that's the meaning. drafting can refer to laws, rules, guidelines, policies etc. But it is not a special term. It is just two words used together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drafting body at a UN organization undertakes the drafting or formulation of guidelines, decisions, resolutions. These drafts are debated, amended and voted on. I understand that the meaning of “to draft” is loose and depends on context. I don’t believe the verb draft always means to compose a first text.
For example, a drafting committee writes and issues the final approved text.

Comment: Thank you! Would you say, then, that this term ("drafting body") is only used in a UN context? Seeing as @FumbleFingers has never heard of drafting bodies, I'm beginning to think I may have misunderstood... I thought "drafting body" was used for any body that prepares cases, in any kind of organisation or authority?

Comment: I understand body as an inexact term that refers to any entity or collection of elements. It sounds important: this august body is entrusted with bla bla bla!

Comment: You have a body of water and doesn’t do anything in terms of writing or preparation. If you were to use committee instead of body it would become clearer I suppose.